# Geolocation getting time out error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I  am really stuck on this issue. I am building an `ionic 2` app. I use `cordova-plugin-geolocation` for location. This is my function to access location ,

```
  getLocation(highAcc: boolean){
    let options = { maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 50000, enableHighAccuracy: highAcc };
    return Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((pos)=>{
      this.long = pos.coords.longitude;
      this.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      return pos;
    }).catch( (err) => {
        return Promise.reject({message: 'unable to access location'});
     });
  }
```

I tried both high accuracy and low but both gives a `time out error`. It works perfectly fine in browser. But the error happens only in android. It sometimes works after a longtime. But never on the first try. And it shows the `location` icon on android when I start the application or the location accessing method. But it almost never returns the `coordinates`.

My app is based on phones location. So I cant move ahead without solving the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I am using the method in my `component`

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.book.getFeedHunts().then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.hunts = res.json();
    }).catch( (err) => {
      this.handleError(err);
    })
}
```

**Note**: I have tried almost all the solutions out there on `stackoverflow`  with no help.

Comment: When high accuracy is engaged on Android, the device must engage GPS hardware and lock satellites which takes time. And indoors it will probably not get a lock. Better to use `watchPosition()` than `getCurrentPosition()` then `clearWatch()` once the first successful position is received.

Comment: I gave it a try. Even that took time. Doesn't ``watchPosition()`` use ``getCurrentPosition`` inside? So can it improve the speed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permissions set for high-accuracy, if missing add this line in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you use Android emulator but not a physical Android device. On an Android emulator, I managed to get geolocation information by following these steps:

1. Set `enableHighAccuracy = true` in your code
2. Run the code by typing CLI command `ionic run android -lc`
3. Open the **Extended Controls** panel on the Android emulator as soon as it launches (see the picture below)
4. On the panel, click **SEND** button to send GPS data to the emulator OS

[image]

Note that it will not work when you set `enableHighAccuracy = false`

Comment: Do not forget to call your code block in the following form;